# single quotes escape during string insertion into a database

Tags: c#, database, insert, special-characters

Insertion fails when "'" is used.
example string is: He's is a boy.
I've attempted to skip the "'" using an escape symbol , but I believe this is not the right way.

```
textBox3.Text.Replace("'", " \'");
string sql= "insert into gtable (1text,1memo) values ('"+textBox3.Text+"',null)";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

I did have the option of replacing "'" with "`" but this changes the text in the db as well. I wish to retain "'" as the same , and also insert it into the db.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

try

```
string sql= "insert into gtable (1text, 1memo) " + 
            "values ('" + textBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "', null)";
```

Comment: this worked man !! thanks. Well how do you use "''" to escape a single quote. Where did you read this. I want to learn about these special characters which the queries won't accept.

Comment: Technically correct answer but that's asking for trouble. Use parameters, as @codingbiz has suggested.

Comment: thk u saved my life

Answer (score 58):

Try this

```
    string sql= "insert into gtable (1text,1memo) values (@col1,NULL)";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1",textBox3.Text);
    con.Open();
```

Comment: +1 By separating the structure of the SQL statement from the data, this eliminates the danger of sql injection (and there is no need to escape anything).

Comment: The issue with this is that it requires a connection, you can't get the "compiled" version? For example, I have a separate unit of work open and just want to execute a manual bit of SQL with a parameter I dont want to have to open a new connection

Answer (score 9):

To insert single quotes in database replace `'` with `''`. In database only single quote will go.

Use this

```
string sql= "insert into gtable (1text,1memo) values ('" 
            + textBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "', null)";
```

Rest code is same.

Comment: This looks like the same as juergen d's answer (_the accepted answer_) but a minute sooner! Why is this not considered?

Comment: @MatinKh: Today is not my day.

Answer (score 2):

On the MSDN article for [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) it says:

> **Returns a new string** in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with another specified Unicode character or String.

On the very first line you are not assigning the value of textBox3.Text to the result of that method call, meaning that absolutely nothing happens.

Furthermore, to escape a quote in SQL Server, you simply use two single-quotes (Note: NOT the same thing as a double-quote).

This should give you the expected outcome:

```
textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''");
```

Additionally, you may wish to look into [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) for your string concatenation needs.

```
String escapedInput = textBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''");
String sql = String.Format("insert into gtable (1text,1memo) values ('{0}',null)", escapedInput);
```

Answer (score -5):

The best way is:

```
string Name = Server.HtmlEncode(txtName.Text);
```

Comment: What does HTML has to do with SQL?