# C# Convert Escape Characters inside string variable into string literal for SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, string, string-literals

I am trying to convert a string variable in C# that contains escape characters like "\r\n" into a string literal so that it can be used in a SQL query.

```
// Here is the value of the string which IS NOT actually a verbatim string literal, but a value passed on from a selected dropdown list.
strEmailText = "We're writing in regard to XXX mentioned above.\r\nPlease contact us.\r\nWe're available by direct reply.\r\nThank you for your assistance."

// Here I create the actual SQL string for use to query the database
strSQL = @"SELECT DISTINCT TBL_EmailText.ID FROM TBL_EmailText WHERE (TBL_EmailText.Text = N'" + strEmailText + "')";
```

Now, whenever I try to search with this SQL string, it converts the escape characters and messes up the query like so:

```
@"SELECT DISTINCT TBL_EmailText.ID FROM TBL_EmailText WHERE (TBL_EmailText.Text = N'We''re writing in regard to XXX mentioned above.

Please contact us.

We''re available by direct reply.

Thank you for your assistance.')"
```

So my question is, how can I get this to work so that it searches using the following:

```
@"SELECT DISTINCT TBL_EmailText.ID FROM TBL_EmailText WHERE (TBL_EmailText.Text = N'We''re writing in regard to XXX mentioned above.\r\nPlease contact us.\r\nWe''re available by direct reply.\r\nThank you for your assistance.')"
```

I have found and tried using this code but it does not work:

```
protected internal static StringWriter ToLiteral(string strString)
    {
        using (StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (CodeDomProvider cdpProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
            {
                cdpProvider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(strString), strWriter, null);
                return strWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

It still converts the escape characters.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [single quotes escape during string insertion into a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912412/single-quotes-escape-during-string-insertion-into-a-database)

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912412/single-quotes-escape-during-string-insertion-into-a-database

Comment: [Hello SQL Injection!](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: Thanks Viacheslav for the response but I do not think you understand my issue. I already know how to fix the apostrophe problem by replacing quotes.  The problem is with escape characters "\r\n" being converted to carriage returns during the SQL query.  I need the "\r\n" escape characters to stay in the SQL query.

Comment: If you save `\r\n`, you'll get `\r\n`... which will be and appears as a new line. A quick hack would be to replace the `\` with `\\`.

Comment: Hi Kilazur I tried the replace with * but after replacing back to \ and searching, it still converted into carriage returns.  Thanks for response!

Comment: Damn, got escaped in the comment. Replace \ with \\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not caused by the escaped characters.  Those only matter to C#.  When the string is concatenated to your sql query, they will just be a regular carriage return and linefeed.

The real problem is caused by using string concatenation in the first place!  You have an apostrophe in your data that will mess up the final query once it is concatenated.

Instead, use a parameterized query and this will not be a problem and you will avoid the sql injection vulnerability too!

```
// Here is the value of the string which IS NOT actually a verbatim string literal, but a value passed on from a selected dropdown list.
strEmailText = "We're writing in regard to XXX mentioned above.\r\nPlease contact us.\r\nWe're available by direct reply.\r\nThank you for your assistance."

// Here I create the actual SQL string for use to query the database
strSQL = @"SELECT DISTINCT TBL_EmailText.ID FROM TBL_EmailText WHERE TBL_EmailText.Text = @EmailText";

using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
{
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@EmailText", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = strEmailText });

    using(SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //Do something with the data
    }
}
```

Note the use of the parameter `@EmailText` in the sql query and how it is added to the `Parameters` collection of the `sqlCmd` object.

This approach will eliminate the problem with apostrophes in the query and, more importantly, the sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

You should not generate SQL sentences with literal strings embedded in it, that's what [query parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx) are for.

Comment: Query parameters fix a host of potential problems like avoiding the remote possibility of SQL injection attacks--particularly if you are using text generated by a user.  https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Okay I will try this and let you know if it works.  Do you know if this method will allow me to use the escape characters as parameters, without converting the carriage returns?

Comment: @ForeverLearningAndCoding If you use parameters you don't need to worry at all about the contents of your strings. The database library/engine handles everything you, no need to escape anything.

Comment: This worked.  Thanks!  I wish I could choose 2 answers for this question but Chris' answer helped me more...

Answer (score 2):

Use a string literal:

```
strEmailText = @"We're writing in regard to XXX mentioned above.\r\nPlease contact us.\r\nWe're available by direct reply.\r\nThank you for your assistance."
```

Also, use parameters in your sql to ensure it is inserted correctly, and to prevent sql injection.

Comment: I can't use string literals as the strings are coming from a dropdown list as mentioned above in the post.  They are passed in and assigned.